# Can I have blocking remote call in Flux.generate state generator

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am generating a Flux from a series of blocking REST API calls, each call depends on the result of previous call. i.e.

```
Result r1 = call(fromRow = 0);
Result r2 = call(fromRow = 0 + r1.size());
Result r3 = call(fromRow = 0 + r1.size() + r2.size());
...
```

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying with:

```
Flux.generate(() -> 0, (i, sink) -> {
    Result r = slowRemoteCall(i);
    if (r == null) {
        sink.complete();
    } else {
        sink.next(r)
    }
    return i + r.size();
}, state -> {});
```

Just wonder will the blocking call `slowRemoteCall` inside the state generator become a problem?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the non-blocking WebClient from Spring for the REST API calls?

Comment: @MartinTarjányi - yes I could use that also. Could you share an example that achieve the same above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may become a problem! If you have any blocking call, you can use `schedulers` to get the task done by specific thread pools.

```
Flux.generate(.........)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
```

More info:

https://www.vinsguru.com/reactive-programming-schedulers/

Answer (score 2):

With `expand` operator and a reactive remote client (e.g.: Spring WebClient) you can implement this in a reactive non-blocking way:

```java
slowRemoteCall(0)
        .expand(result -> {
            if (result.size() == 0) { // stop condition
                return Mono.empty();
            } else {
                return slowRemoteCall(result.startIndex() + result.size()); // maintain state
            }
        })

Mono<Result> slowRemoteCall(int startIndex) {
    // simulate latency (could be a WebClient call here)
    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(200)).thenReturn(new Result(startIndex));
}
```

Inspired by [this blog post](https://bsideup.github.io/posts/daily_reactive/pagination/).